# DatabaseTheory: Difference between 'many to one' and 'many to onlyOne' relationship

Tags: entity-relationship, database-theory

What is the difference between 'many to one' and 'many to onlyOne' relationships?

I don't know if it is referred to by another term, but the 'onlyOne' end of a relationship is usually marked by a curved arrow in ER diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

This is about the minimum cardinality, also called participation. The participation indicates whether all the entity occurrences, for a given entity set, have to participate in the relationship or not. In other words, is the participation mandatory or optional?

In this case the rounded/curved arrow indicates mandatory participation, so each entity occurrence **has** to take part in the relationship.

Example:
entities Employee and Department, linked by a relationship WorksFor which is a one-to-many relationship (an Employee works for one Department, and a Department can have multiple Employees working in there). Assuming each Employee has to be associated with at least one Department, so the participation is mandatory, you can define its cardinality as "one and only one" (or "exactly one").

Note: there are many ER notations out there (Chen's, UML, many more), so the rounded/curved arrow is not the only way to express a mandatory participation. The important aspect is to be consistent with the notation. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Diagramming_conventions

Answer (score -1):

one to many example would be below:
Customers table has the below fields
customerId, customerName

Orders table has the below fields
orderId, customerId, amount

The relationship between Customers and Orders table is 1 to many i.e. 1 customer can place many orders.

Many to Many example would be below:
Questions table (like in stackoverflow) with fields
questionId, question

Tags table with fields
tagId, tagType(Database, C++ etc)

This is an example of many to many relationship i.e. a question can have many tags and a tag can belong to many questions. You need a seperate table to maintain this mapping.

i.e.
TagQuestionMapping
tagId, questionId

Comment: but what about 'many to *OnlyOne*' relationships, how are they different from 'many to one', couldnt find any info on this anywhere